# Question about circumcircle and tangent & angle bisectors at a point of the triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If the tangent at $A$ to the circumcircle $ABC$ meets $BC$ at $X$ then prove $XA=XD=XD'$ where $D$ and $D'$ are the points where the internal and external bisectors of $A$ meet $BC$ respectively.

I have not been able to find/use any theorems relating to the fact that $AX$ is a tangent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In the figure, since $AX$ is tangent to the circle, by angles in alternative segement we have:
$$\angle XAB = \angle ACB$$

Suppose the angle bisector of $A$ meets $BC$ at $D$. (I forgot to name it)

Then $\angle XAD = \angle XAB + \angle BAD = \angle ACB + \angle CAD$ (angle bisector) $=\angle BDA$ (exterior angle of triangle)

This equality gives $XA = XD$.

The other part can be done by observing the interior and exterior angle bisectors are perpendicular.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, elegant solution